# DRF serializer change field to read_only for some model instances

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have this model:

```
class Task(MPTTModel, TimeStampedModel, StartFinishModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self',
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            related_name='children')
    start_date = models.DateField()    
    finish_date = models.DateField()
    @property
    def is_stage(self):
        if self.get_children():
            return True
        return False
```

And serializer:

```
class TaskBaseSerializer(StartFinishSerializer, TimeStampedSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'parent', 'start_date', 'finish_date', 'is_stage')    
        read_only_fields = ('is_stage')
```

I want to make fields `'start_date'` and `'finish_date'` to become read_only if `is_stage` property is *True*. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to override `__init__()` method like this:

```
class TaskBaseSerializer(StartFinishSerializer, TimeStampedSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'parent', 'start_date', 'finish_date', 'is_stage')    
        read_only_fields = ('is_stage')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TaskBaseSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance and getattr(self.instance, 'is_stage', None):
            self.fields['start_date'].read_only = True
            self.fields['finish_date'].read_only = True
```

Comment: nice! only what - had to change `if self.instance and type(self.instance) != TreeQuerySet and self.instance.is_stage:` cuz that serializer shows both list of tasks and single task and throws error in case of list view. P.S. Ah, i see you have updated your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Also the same result can be achieved with:

```
def get_fields(self):
    fields = super(TaskBaseSerializer, self).get_fields()
    if self.instance and getattr(self.instance, 'is_stage', None):
        fields['start_date'].read_only = True
        fields['finish_date'].read_only = True
    return fields
```