# Django Rest Framework serilaizers limit the choices

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

`choices.py`

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

ACCESS_CHOICES = (
(1, _("super_admin")),
(2, _("admin")),
(3, _("accountant")),
(4, _("consultant"))
)
```

`models.py`

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name="works",
        on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    access = models.IntegerField(choices=app.choices.ACCESS_CHOICES)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class MyUPDATESerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['access']
```

I would like to limit the choices shown to a user during update through the serializers. 
Eg:

`ACCESS_CHOICES = (
(3, _("accountant")),
(4, _("consultant")))`

or

`ACCESS_CHOICES = (
(2, _("admin")),
(4, _("consultant")))`

The choices shown depends on the user updating  the access. How to achieve this?

Comment: Looks like you have to overwrite `__init__` method of serializer. Yesterday I had similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/52424854/8495108. May be that will help.

Comment: @Chiefir I am aware of the `__init__` method. But how to limit the fields choices(tuple of choices) to a few.

Comment: I did not work with that, but I assume that choice tuple should be stored somewhere in the field context, so you have to find it and overwrite by the choises what you want for different cases.